# Calculate average of values in R and add result as new rows instead of as a new column

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-analysis

I have a dataframe like the following one:

```
day year    value
1   2014    5   
1   2015    16  
1   2016    0   
2   2014    3   
2   2015    1   
2   2016    4
```

and I want to calculate the average value by day for the three year period (2014, 2015, 2016). The following code works for this purpose:

```
data  %>% 
  group_by(day) %>% 
  mutate(MEAN = mean(value))
```

and produces this output:

```
day year    value  MEAN
1   2014    5      7
1   2015    16     7
1   2016    0      7
2   2014    3      3
2   2015    1      3
2   2016    4      3
```

but I want to add the average values as new rows in the same dataframe as follows:

```
day year    value
1   2014    5   
1   2015    16  
1   2016    0   
2   2014    3   
2   2015    1   
2   2016    4
1   avg     7 <--
2   avg     3 <--
```

Any suggestions about how can I possibly do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `summarise` (instead of `mutate` - which adds a new column in the original dataset) to calculate the `mean` and then with `bind_rows` can bind with original data.  The tidyverse functions are very particular about `type`, so make sure the `class` are the same before we do the binding

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   group_by(day) %>%
   summarise(year = 'avg', value = mean(value)) %>% 
   bind_rows(data %>% 
               mutate(year = as.character(year)), .)
#  day year value
#1   1 2014  5.00
#2   1 2015 16.00
#3   1 2016  0.00
#4   2 2014  3.00
#5   2 2015  1.00
#6   2 2016  4.00
#7   1  avg  7.00
#8   2  avg  2.67
```

---

Another option is to split by the 'day' and then with `add_row` (from `tibble`) create a new row on each of the `list` elements

```
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
data %>% 
  mutate(year = as.character(year)) %>% 
  group_split(day) %>% 
  map_dfr(~ .x %>% add_row(day = first(.$day),
       year = 'avg', value = mean(.$value)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `aggregate`

```
rbind(df,cbind(aggregate(value~day,df,mean),year = "avg")[c(1,3,2)])
```

or a variation (by @thelatemail from comments)

```
rbind(df, aggregate(df["value"], cbind(df["day"], year="avg"), FUN=mean))
```

which gives

```
  day year     value
1   1 2014  5.000000
2   1 2015 16.000000
3   1 2016  0.000000
4   2 2014  3.000000
5   2 2015  1.000000
6   2 2016  4.000000
7   1  avg  7.000000
8   2  avg  2.666667
```

Comment: Variation on a theme - `rbind(dat, aggregate(dat["value"], cbind(dat["day"], year="avg"), FUN=mean))`

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks! I added yours to the answer as well